# No Portland to Detroit direct flight?

Tags: air-travel, detroit, portland

I'm not familiar with flying from Portland, Oregon, to Detroit, but I need to acquire some data for a situation I'm involved in. Based on Google Flights, I cannot find a single direct flight from Portland to Detroit in the future. I am not sure if this is due to COVID, or if this is just the normal situation.

Is there anyone who has flown this route before and can share some insight?

If there was no direct flight form Portland to Detroit, I would be a bit surprised. Detroit is a major airport. Portland is medium sized airport, and I would expect at least 1 or 2 direct flights to Detroit a day.

Is there a website where I can search if there were direct flights in the past?

Comment: Which Portland?

Comment: Not sure about direct flights in past but there is a direct flight by Delta starting in May, 2021. https://www.delta.com/flight-status/1/0841/2021-05-19/PDX/DTW

Comment: You can also search past flights on the Bureau of transportation statistic [website](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/ONTIME/Departures.aspx). I did a query on January 2020 with Delta and I could see direct flights from PDX to DTW.

Comment: @Aak that sounds like an answer

Comment: @mlc it's a half-answer as OP also asked if someone has actually traveled on the mentioned route. should I remove comments and post them as the answer ?

Comment: Are you asking about direct or non-stop? These are (unfortunately) VERY different things for some airlines.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Oregon one.

Comment: @Aak For the Bureau stat link, do you know if there's some trick to specifying both the depparture and arrival airports? Currently, I only see an option to list a departure airport

Comment: @Hilmar Non-stop. I thought the 2 were interchangeable.

Comment: Detroit, OR is less than 100 miles from Portland. Surely you don't need to fly ;)

Comment: @student010101: Unfortunately they are not.. A direct flight can include a stop. Some airlines just combine two random flights, give  them the same flight number and market it as "direct". Case in point I was on a direct flight from Boston to Vegas and had tp spend the night in Denver since I missed the connection. Direct sometimes just means that two legs have the same flight number. It does NOT mean the same plane, the same crew, the same gate or non-stop.

Answer (score 9):

Alaska and Delta have both flown PDX-DTW nonstops in the recent past (5 years).

Alaska had a redeye in 2017, but as [reported at FlyerTalk](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/alaska-airlines-mileage-plan/1876856-pdx-dtw-service-ending-jan-2018-a.html) and confirmed in their [archived January 2019 timetable](https://web.archive.org/web/20191017161302/https://resource.alaskaair.net/-/media/Files/pdf/AlaskaAirlines-January19-AIM?v=1), this was changed to a seasonal route and then discontinued altogether.

Delta inherited the DTW hub (and PDX-DTW) with its 2008 merger with Northwest Airlines. According to their [archived November 2019 timetable](https://content.delta.com/content/dam/delta-www/pdfs/flight_schedules.pdf), they were operating one flight per day during the off season.

My armchair analyst's suspicion is that there is not enough demand for this route to justify more service. Alaska would want to route connecting passengers through its larger hub at SEA, and as for Delta, they have been focused on building up JFK and LAX, although the route is likely to return after the COVID-19 shock fades.

As for low-cost carriers, Southwest and Spirit serve both airports, but neither seems to have been interested in the route.

Comment: Based on @Aak's comment above, it seems Delta will have a direct flight in May? So maybe it's currently affected by COVID?

Comment: I stated this directly in my answer.

Comment: As of summer 2023 Delta is now operating one flight per day between PDX and DTW.  The eastbound leg is a redeye flight.